# Scheduling a lot of tasks on back-end, Node.js

Tags: node.js, neo4j, cron, scheduling, backend

Let's say I have a database (`Neo4j` to be specific with `Node.js` back-end) full of stores (millions of them) that have opening and closing time. And I need to update each database store entry as opened or closed on appropriate time. So what is the best/usual practice of building such a system in stable and scalable way?

Setting millions of cron jobs?
Checking for entries to change in fixed time intervals?
Third party service able to call my backend for changes on specific time?

Comment: If the store open/close time is known ahead of time, why does it have to be written to the database each time it opens or closes?  Why can't one just fetch the store hours from the database and do a calculation to determine if it's currently open or closed?  Then, you don't have to update the database at all except when planned store hours change.

Comment: Totally agree with @jfriend00, I would totally set flag ```open=bool``` to true only when I'm asked to determine this information on retrieval. It really depends on your use case. Can you be maybe more specific, what is the use of this?

Comment: @TomHert 
It seems that my example is not the best, lets assume that at some point of time we should transform this `Store` object from `Store` to available for rent `Property`, that what i want to schedule. i.e i will change label of neo4j node from `Store` to `Property`. Why i want to do this? To keep out empty `Property` from `Store` search. But now i'm thinking maybe im going the wrong way and it's indeed better to make indexing, filter timestamps on each search  and treat not yet past  as `Stores` and others as empty `Property`.

Comment: @jfriend00 check out my comment.

Comment: though im not sure will i loose some performance if i will filter on indexed node properies instead of looking only through `Store` nodes. But i suppose building scheduling system that will just change booleans for millions of entries doesn't worth this performance gain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking about is how to tradeoff writing info to the database (for potentially millions of objects) in order to speed up the performance when future queries are made.  This is an age old tradeoff and there is no set answer that works for all situations.  Everything here is a tradeoff.

On the one hand, millions of database writes should pretty much be avoided at nearly all cost because that's the most expensive thing you can do to your database server.

On the other hand, having to do lots of very inefficient queries is rarely to most optimized position to be either.

So, it really comes down to evaluating where in the tradeoff space you should set things.

These are the kinds of questions you'd ask yourself to determine which direction in the tradeoff to go:

1. Are your queries too slow now and in dire need of performance improvement.
2. If you were going to restructure part of the database to make the "too slow" queries faster, how much of a performance improvement in the query speed do you get (you must measure before/after performance to analyze this).
3. How often and how many objects do you have to change in the database in order to keep things optimized.  If only a few objects change each day, then that's an easy optimization to run each day.  But, if millions change all the time, then you probably won't want to write to the database that often.
4. Does your site/database have a very slow time each day (like the middle of the night in your target market) that you could afford to do some sort of "batch" job on it to optimize it without impacting the regular use of the database in a noticeable way?
5. Can you design a separate optimization app that works on optimizing the database, but does so at a slow, maintained rate such that it doesn't negatively impact the real-time use of the database?

So, deciding how much to restructure the database to improve query performance is a continuous tradeoff between these various factors.  You can likely only find the ideal tradeoff spot to be by designing some tests and taking a bunch of measurements.  Remember that premature optimization (optimizing before you've proven you have a problem worth solving) is pretty much wasted code writing and testing time that could be better spent on more valuable tasks.  But, solving problems that you've proven through testing are measured and real can be a very efficient use of resources.

As to your original questions:

> Setting millions of cron jobs?

No.  This is just not going to be a good performing solution.

> Checking for entries to change in fixed time intervals?

This is one possibility.  It depends upon how "current" you need the database to be.  If you could run some sort of optimization pass every hour and you could manage the writes to the database so that they didn't cause undue stress on the database so the real-time use of the database wasn't adversely impacted, then this could work.  Even better would be some sort of optimization pass you could run at night when your database is otherwise not being used much.

> Third party service able to call my backend for changes on specific
>   time?

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by third party service.  Regardless of what you're doing, you likely don't want the database optimization code to be running in your main node.js process that serves as your app server.  It should be a separate app/process that can use a separate CPU from your main node.js server.

Comment: Wow, thanks for such detailed answer! Good points.
By 3rd party i was imagining some PaaS-kind thingy, to which you can dump your tasks and it will take care of doing those tasks and scaling. 
Yes i think i will go for 'inefficient' queries for now and will look at performance, if it's bad then i could build some worker that will slowly 'clean up' database in fixed time intervals to optimize...
Do you have any other options on your mind apart from doing work in fixed time intervals? Or that looks like the only sane way?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to come up with a good solution -- and this has nothing to do in particular with neo4J, nodeJS or anything else -- without some extra information. Why doe the database represent open/closed in a way that needs such intensive updating? Why not have each store hold the hours its open in a declarative way, i.e. 9am-5pm Monday-Friday? Exceptions can be added. (Interestingly this was an interesting question on SO just a few years ago: [Efficiently determining if a business is open or not based on store hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/775161/efficiently-determining-if-a-business-is-open-or-not-based-on-store-hours/775247#775247)) Since most stores open and close on hour or half-hour boundaries, your proposed solution will have a database with no write activity except a few seconds per hour, when a massive fraction of the database needs to be updated.

Consider pre-calculating in a more efficient way. Or calculating any given store on demand and caching the answer.

Comment: Well mainly i wanted to do scheduling to effectively cleanup and change database. Its more of an expiration time that a really closing time, i.e this 'shop' closes once and for all and at this time i wanted to make a cleanup - disconnect users from chat linked to it, remove chat itself, change shop Node's title to something that will represent 'history' i.e shop that once was there. i cant cache response as there is much more filtering going on - including geolocarion name e.t.c.

Comment: for now i think to go for just indexing start-end time and include this check in to each query. And make cleanup on some subsequent requests instead of scheduling them. Though i still will need to always check for those end/start time in eqch store search request.
Another option would be to close them on demand, which will solve all the problems, but anyway I just trying to wrap my head around all of the possibilities that i have here.

Comment: And yes, that's a good point, there will be pretty dsitinctive time boundaries  in which most of the stores will be closed, so in case of scheduling a lot of data should be updated at once. Which sounds less and less effective.